# Pass additional arguments to the function passed in map()

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to pass a function to map() which need to use additional data (for example data passed as arguments to the scala program).

For example:

I have a list:

```
val myList = List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

and a multiplier value is passed as command line argument.

```
val multiplier = args(0) // In this example, let it be 2
```

and I have a function

```
def multiply(a: Int, b: Int) = a*b
```

Now I want to perform map() on my List as below:

```
myList.map(multiply)
```

Of course this doesn't work because, map expects only one argument (which in this case is element of list).

Please help me how can pass functions to map which use additional arguments.

Comment: You may use `myList.map (_ * multiplier)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish this with [currying](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala)

```
def multiply(a: Int)(b: Int) = a*b
myList.map(multiply(multiplier))
```

Or, if `multiply` isn't your method:

```
val multiplyCurried = Function.curried(multiply _)
myList.map(multiplyCurried(multiplier))
```